Given n arguments of expected type T<A, B>, infer each couple of type parameters
This is about correctly typing the declaration of a generic variadic function that accepts a list of arguments of a generic type requiring multiple type parameters so that at call site, the type parameters can be inferred for each argument.
The following lines are aimed at constructing a simple instance of this problem.
With only one type parameter
Let us consider the type:
type O1<T> = { a: T, b: NoInfer<T> };

and two generic functions of one parameter of type O1<T>, typed differently:
function f1T<T>(arg: O1<T>) {}
function f1O<T, G extends O1<T>>(arg: G) {}

If we call each of them with a simple object literal, one of them works as expected, while the other does not:
f1T/*<number>*/({ a: 0, b: ''}); // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number' (ok)
f1O/*<unknown, { a: number, b: string }>*/({ a: 0, b: ''}); // is accepted (not ok)

The declaration of f1O presumably implies an inference at call site of G first. Trying to match our argument against O1 would lead to a type parameter of type unknown, which would then be the type assigned to T.
We can write a variadic function based on f1T:
function fmT<Ts extends unknown[]>(...args: { [K in keyof Ts]: O1<Ts[K]> }) {}

fmT({ a: 0, b: 1 }, { a: '0', b: 2 }); // [b: 2] Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string' (ok)

It works as intended.
With two type parameters
There is no difficulty following the same model for one argument:
type O4<T, U> = { a: T, b: NoInfer<T>, c: U, d: NoInfer<U> };
function f1TU<T, U>(arg: O4<T, U>) {}

f1TU({ a: 0, b: 1, c: '', d: 2 }); // [d] Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string' (ok)

With two, however, it no longer seems so straightforward.
Here are a few examples of code that could be written... none of which provides an actual solution.

The naive approach illustrates both what is expected from fmTU and the origin of the problem that arises:
function fmTU_naive<Ts extends unknown[], Us extends unknown[]>(...args: {
  [K in keyof Ts]: O4<Ts[K], Us[K]> 
}) {}
// Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'Us'.


Using an intersection of keys breaks the mapped tuple:
function fmTU_inter<Ts extends unknown[], Us extends unknown[]>(...args: {
  [K in (keyof Ts & keyof Us)]: O4<Ts[K], Us[K]> 
}) {}
// A rest parameter must be of an array type.


Using a conditional breaks the inference:
function fmTU_cond<Ts extends unknown[], Us extends unknown[]>(...args: {
  [K in keyof Ts]: AsNumber<K> extends keyof Us ? O4<Ts[K], Us[AsNumber<K>]> : never;
}) {}
fmTU_cond/*<[number], unknown[]>*/({ a: 0, b: 1, c: '', d: 2 }); // is accepted (not ok)

Note: AsNumber<K> is used because in practice a tuple type is not inferred for Us, and string indices thus don't extend keyof Us.
type AsNumber<S> = S extends `${infer N extends number}` ? N : never;


Grouping each couple of type parameters in a tuple requires referencing them through an index, which also seems to break the inference process:
function fmTU_index<const TUs extends [T: unknown, U: unknown][]>(...args: {
  [K in keyof TUs]: O4<TUs[K][0], TUs[K][1]>;
}) {}
fmTU_index/*<[T: unknown, U: unknown][]>*/({ a: 0, b: 1, c: '', d: 2 }); // is accepted (not ok)



Forgoing the prospect of finding a direct way of writing this, it is possible to write a helper type to infer an actual O4 type from O4<unknown, unknown> and write a usable fmO:
const TS_ERROR = Symbol();
type TSError<Msg extends string> = { [TS_ERROR]: Msg };

type InferO4<O extends O4<unknown, unknown>> =
  O extends O4<unknown, unknown> ?
    O['a'] extends infer T ?
      O['b'] extends T ?
        O['c'] extends infer U ?
          O['d'] extends U ?
            O4<T, U> :
          TSError<'Type O[\'d\'] is not assignable to type O[\'c\']'> : 
        never :    
      TSError<'Type O[\'b\'] is not assignable to type O[\'a\']'> :
    never :
  TSError<'Type O is not assignable to type O4<unknown, unknown>'>;

type InferO4s<Os extends O4<unknown, unknown>[]> = { [K in keyof Os]: InferO4<Os[K]> };


function fmO_helper<
  Os extends O4<unknown, unknown>[],
  Is = InferO4s<Os>
>(
  ...args: Os & InferO4s<Os>
) {};


fmO_helper(
  { a: 0, b: 1, c: '0', d: '1'},
  { a: Symbol(), b: 0, c: 0, d: 1}
);
// Is: [O4<number, string>, TSError<"Type O['b'] is not assignable to type O['a']">] (ok)


• Is this a question? Are you saying "it is possible" where you mean "is it possible"? • You can do it a "direct" way by intersecting two homomorphic mapped types; one for Ts and the other for Us, as shown in this playground link. (I'm not jazzed that TS shows the error on the whole arg list instead of just the offending argument, but the error message at least explains where the problem is.) Does that meet your needs?  If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

• "it is possible" essentially meant "well I guess I can still go the hacky way" • That. Is. Exactly. What I needed. The holy constraint. Thank you very much for commenting.

I'll write an answer soon.

If you want to infer a type argument from a mapped type, it needs to be a homomorphic mapped type over the type parameter in question (see What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?).  This used to be documented in the handbook but the newest version of the handbook doesn't seem to mention it.
So if you want to infer Ts you need {[I in keyof Ts]: ⋯Ts[I]⋯ } and if you want to infer Us you need, separately, {[I in keyof Us]: ⋯Us[I]⋯ }.  You can't combine Ts and Us inside the mapped type, since then you'll break the homomorphic mapping (or it won't be homomorphic in either Ts or Us directly). The only way I know that works is to use an intersection of the mapped types. TypeScript is good-ish about inferring from intersections (see the resolution of microsoft/TypeScript#7234):
function fmTU<Ts extends unknown[], Us extends Record<keyof Ts, unknown>>(...args:
  { [K in keyof Ts]: O4<Ts[K], unknown> } &
  { [K in keyof Us]: O4<unknown, Us[K]> }
) { }

Luckily your O4<T, U> type is covariant in T and U (see Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript) so O4<Ts[K], Us[K]> is assignable to both O4<Ts[K], unknown> and O4<unknown, US[K]>. It lets us infer each type argument separately.
Let's test it:
fmTU(
  { a: 0, b: 1, c: '', d: "" },
  { a: null, b: null, c: 3, d: 4 },
  { a: 0, b: 1, c: '', d: "" }
); // okay
/* function fmTU<[number, null, number], [string, number, string]>(...*/

fmTU(
  { a: 0, b: 1, c: '', d: "" }, // error!
  { a: null, b: null, c: 3, d: 4 }, // error!
  { a: 0, b: 1, c: '', d: 2 } // error!
); // error! Type at position 2 in source is not compatible
/* function fmTU<[number, null, number], [string, number, string]>(...*/

Looks good. The Ts and Us type arguments are inferred as desired. When you make a mistake, you get an error. Unfortunately that error highlights the entire list of arguments as a problem, instead of just the one with the mistake. The error message mentions which argument is the problem (with a 0-indexed position), so you should hopefully be able to fix it.
It would be nice if there were some more intuitive way to infer multiple type arguments like this, but I don't know of any.
Playground link to code

mostly about style: Using Record<keyof Ts, unknown> is arguably a bit treacherous, since it is not technically a mapped tuple/array. To make it clearer that Us has the same the number of keys as Ts, which can be derived from the intersection anyway, we now need the intersection to let TypeScript know that the rest parameter is of an array type. Furthermore, if we now wanted all elements of Us to be arrays, it would be easy to write Record<keyof Ts, unknown[]> and we'd just have TypeScript expect an array whose property length (among others) is an array...
